# Asynchronous script load issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to load a script from an external source after the user executes a `click` function. Like so:

```
$("#test-button").click(function() {
$.getScript("http://someurl.com/widget/javascript?key=4&t=uid&q=94777&show=all", function (data) {
        $('#myDiv').append(data);
    });
 });
```

The script I'm loading (which I have no control over) includes a `document.write`, so I'm getting this error when I execute the `click`:

*It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.*

I'm not sure how to get around this. I thought `getScript` would manage this.

Comment: If it contains document.write, you will not be able to add it like that or add it dynamically.

Comment: @epascarello That's what I thought. Any other work around besides an iframe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53945/dynamically-inserting-javascript-into-html-that-uses-document-write

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have append the script like text

please see this example

```
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.src = '../web3.0/lib/charts/google-charts.js';
            document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: This will have the same error that the OP had. See: https://plnkr.co/edit/n60VzATrZHnZkYsxLHLv?p=preview